# How do file objects get stored uploaded from a website

Tags: database, file, file-storage

What design is used to store file objects that gets loaded from a website. For instance if I have a website that accepts documents or images. So 
Use Case 1. 
Users logs in and selects a MS word file on his machine and uploads to the website.
Use Case 2.
User logs in and selects a image on his machine and uploads to the website.

How do I store these file objects in the database

Comment: Please provide more details about what database you are using, and what your code looks like. This ends up being very specific to both the code/CMS and the DB in use.

Comment: PostGress using an AngularJS application

Answer (score 0):

The first step is just getting the file from the AngularJS application to the server. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) talks about sending request to the server from the client and should get you started.

Once you have done that, (assuming you are using PHP) you will need to save the resulting file to the database. [This post](http://www.fuzzy.cz/en/articles/storing-files-in-a-postgresql-database) will get you started with saving files to PostgreSQL, but the details will end up being very specific to your situation:

If you have more questions after reading through those resources please add specific details about your setup to your question.